# Igraph Random Graph

Tags: graph, python-3.4, igraph

I want to create a graph in python using Igraph. I did not create the edges. I want to know how to create the random edges between the nodes that have already been created. I tried to use `Graph.GRG` but it did not work.

`g.add_vertices(3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`g.add_edges()` is what you need. This method takes a list of pairs of vertex numbers. Here is a simple example:

```
from igraph import * 
import random

## Generate graph with 8 vertices and no edges
g = Graph()
g.add_vertices(8)

## Now generate random edges
random.seed(123)
RandEdges = []
for x in range(1, 13):
    RandEdges.append(random.sample(range(0,g.vcount()), 2))
RandEdges
[[0, 2],
 [1, 6],
 [6, 2],
 [1, 6],
 [0, 3],
 [5, 2],
 [0, 1],
 [2, 7],
 [5, 7],
 [3, 1],
 [0, 3],
 [1, 4]]
```

With this format,  you can add the edges.

```
## Add edges and plot
g.add_edges(RandEdges)
plot(g)
```

[image: Graph with random edges]

Some additional examples of adding edges are available in the [igraph tutorial](http://igraph.org/python/doc/tutorial/tutorial.html)